# Accessing a variable declared in another rb file

Tags: ruby

this is a begginer question about including .rb files.

I would like to have access to an array declared in another rb file. My main program goes like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
load 'price.rb'
[...]
max_price = price[az][type] * 2
[...]
```

and here is the price.rb :

```
price = {'us-east-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'c1.medium' => 0.165, 'm1.large' => 0.320 },
'us-west-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'c1.medium' => 0.165, 'm1.large' => 0.320 },
'eu-west-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.085, 'c1.medium' => 0.186, 'm1.large' => 0.340 }
}
```

When I run the main script I get this error :

```
Error: undefined local variable or method `price' for main:Object
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Depending on where you need that array to be available, you can adjust the scope of the variable using this guide: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

Comment: Thank you for the link! that helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to export data from one file and make use of it in another is either a class or a module.

An example is:

```
# price.rb
module InstancePrices
  PRICES = {
    'us-east-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, ... },
    ...
  }
end
```

In another file you can `require` this. Using `load` is incorrect.

```
require 'price'

InstancePrices::PRICES['us-east-1']
```

You can even shorten this by using `include`:

```
require 'price'

include InstancePrices
PRICES['us-east-1']
```

What you've done is a bit difficult to use, though. A proper object-oriented design would encapsulate this data within some kind of class and then provide an interface to that. Exposing your data directly is counter to those principles.

For instance, you'd want a method `InstancePrices.price_for('t1.micro', 'us-east-1')` that would return the proper pricing. By separating the internal structure used to store the data from the interface you avoid creating huge dependencies within your application.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring the variable inside a tiny and simple class would be the cleaner solution imho.

Answer (score 3):

A quote from a [Ruby forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/55540):

> Keep in mind that using load keeps local variables local to their scope
>   within the file.

Which means that you can use the *price* variable only if it is not local; an example with instance variable:

```
@price = {'us-east-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'c1.medium' => 0.165, 'm1.large' => 0.320 }, 'us-west-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.08, 'c1.medium' => 0.165, 'm1.large' => 0.320 }, 'eu-west-1' => {'t1.micro' => 0.02, 'm1.small' => 0.085, 'c1.medium' => 0.186, 'm1.large' => 0.340 } }
```

Comment: Please don't declare instance variables in a global context.

Comment: It's very bad form. Instance variables are supposed to exist within the context of a specific class. They're also not useful in any scope outside of the default scope.

Comment: @tadman - Each question has its own context, what's wrong with, according to you, my answer in this context? Please leave aside the quantum physics theory for a moment.

Comment: Global instance variables are not available inside a class, that's a different context, so they're pretty much useless. That's what I mean. What do you mean by quantum physics? I'm not even sure where that came from.

Comment: By "context" I am referring specifically to Ruby's concept of context.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access variable from another file, **but you can access function from another file**:

file1.rb

```rb
# in case of script you may use 'global' variables (with $) 
# as they have scope visibility to this whole file 
$foo = 'bar'

def getFoo
    $foo
end
```

file2.rb

```rb
require_relative 'file1.rb'
foo = getFoo
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think forget about files.

Think about classes and methods.

A couple of options are:

- put these methods and variable inside a class in one .rb file.
- put the variables and method in different file and `include` them

You'll need to think classes and methods and includes and extends to have a solution that makes sense.